# Flight traveling from Glasgow to Kolkata

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines

I am going to Kolkata,India for my marriage and after marriage I would like to bring my wife with me here in Glasgow,UK. If I book ticket for my wife with me together from Kolkata to Glasgow , price is expensive since it is one way and If I book return ticket for me and one way for my wife in same flight it again expensive plus I am not sure that weather we will be allocated seats near to each other or not ? Could anyone tell me the solution to book flight ticket for me and my wife at cheap price ?

Comment: With many companies you can pay a little extra to book a specific seat.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Sorry but we don't do bookings nor can we help you look for the cheapest options for this flight. This is really a travel agent's job.